# property window of local file or folder?

Tags: java, swing, file, properties

Is there any way in java that I can see property window of local file in my Java Swing program?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you want to open this dialog from a Swing application or do you want to recreate this dialog with Swing components?

Comment: This is potentially a WIN32 subject (uses shell32.dll as I think)

Comment: @Guillaume Polet: I want to open this dialog in swing application using java code. Is there any way to access that dialog?

Comment: *"Is there any way to access that dialog?"* Not on *nix or OS X,  Which begs the question, why use Java?  Note that it is possible to find some of the details seen in the Windows file info. pop-up using the `File` class.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985122/show-explorers-properties-dialog-for-a-file-in-windows) talks about doing this in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard Swing API for opening that dialog but you can still do it in Java using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md) which allows you to access native shared libraries with only Java code.

@Guillaume Polet has posted a link to a similar question with a [Python implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936682/how-do-i-display-a-files-properties-dialog-from-c). You would have to get that code and translate it to Java. Alternatively, here's a [C# example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936682/how-do-i-display-a-files-properties-dialog-from-c).

With the JNA tutorial and those examples you should be able to write a Java implementation.