# Qt / PyQt: How to open native file properties dialogue on given path?

Tags: qt, file, properties, pyqt, pyqt4

While writing my current app I've found that I want to add context menu item and shortcut that calls native system file/folder `Properties` dialog for the object that represents a file or dir (with full path, certainly).

Googling for one hour and a half wasn't gave me even simple result.
I've tried to search for `rundll32` cl parameters and others. Some examples was in C# or VBS but it doesn't fit to my problem.

And actually, there's no possibility to use `pyWi32` - only `PyQt`.

There are two questions:

1. Is there a way to show that damn native dialog at least on Windows?
2. Is it much difficult with solving this kind of problems on Linux or Mac?

**UPD:** Thanks for comments. [There is actually a post that duplicates my question with working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985122/show-explorers-properties-dialog-for-a-file-in-windows). I think that my question might be closed as duplicate but second question isn't answered yet :(

Comment: Why exactly do you need the native properties dialog? Is there some specific feature that you can't implement yourself?

Comment: @ekhumoro, I'm writing program that tightly works with files and folders and it's very useful to have direct access to native properties dialog. The usecases is infinite.

Comment: @Lego, Thank you! Sure I missed that. But it works as a charm :) Maybe you something that helps to make it on *Mac* and *Linux*?

Comment: Even though I was the final close voter, I upvoted the question for your graciousness. Plus you made me laugh when I got to "damn native dialog" :-)